# How to draw a chessboard with numbers?

Tags: chessboard

How to draw a chessboard filled with numbers, as the following figure?

[image: wanted]

I've tried using the [`chessboard`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chessboard) package but to no success.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) will help us help you. :-)

Comment: Please review the answers to your other questions and accept them when applicable... Regarding this question, you have to show us what you've tried so far. Post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: See the [PGF-TikZ Manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (for version 3.0) sec. 2.20 pag. 42.

Comment: It is unclear how do I the external numbering of rows and columns

Comment: This is not a chessboard: There are no dark fields, the columns are numbered instead of using a-h. There are no chess pieces. It's an 8x8 tabular with row and column numbers. The chessboard package is the wrong tool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really want to use a chessboard...

[image: chess board]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessfss}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\newlength{\symsize}\setlength{\symsize}{24pt}
\newlength{\boardwidth}\setlength{\boardwidth}{8\symsize}
\setboardfontsize{\symsize}

\newcommand{\board}[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\fbox{\parbox{\boardwidth}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{\symsize}#1}}}
\newcommand{\row}[1]{\parbox[c][\symsize]{\symsize}{\hfill{#1}}}
\newcommand{\col}[1]{\parbox[b]{\symsize}{\hfil{#1}}}
\newcommand{\chessboard}[1]{\begin{tabular}{cc}
\parbox{\symsize}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{\symsize}
\row{8} \row{7} \row{6} \row{5} \row{4} \row{3} \row{2} \row{1}}&\board{#1}\\
\row{ } &\mbox{\col{a}\col{b}\col{c}\col{d}\col{e}\col{f}\col{g}\col{h}}
\end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\TextOnWhite}[1]{\WhiteEmptySquare\hspace{-\symsize}%
\raisebox{.35\symsize}{\makebox[\symsize][c]{\small #1}}}
\newcommand{\TextOnBlack}[1]{\BlackEmptySquare\hspace{-\symsize}%
\raisebox{.35\symsize}{\makebox[\symsize][c]{\small #1}}}

\begin{document}
\large

\begin{center}\chessboard{
\TextOnWhite{(8,1)}\TextOnBlack{(8,2)}\TextOnWhite{(8,3)}\TextOnBlack{(8,4)}%
\TextOnWhite{(8,5)}\TextOnBlack{(8,6)}\TextOnWhite{(8,7)}\TextOnBlack{(8,8)}\\
\TextOnBlack{(7,1)}\TextOnWhite{(7,2)}\TextOnBlack{(7,3)}\TextOnWhite{(7,4)}%
\TextOnBlack{(7,5)}\TextOnWhite{(7,6)}\TextOnBlack{(7,7)}\TextOnWhite{(7,8)}\\
\TextOnWhite{(6,1)}\TextOnBlack{(6,2)}\TextOnWhite{(6,3)}\TextOnBlack{(6,4)}%
\TextOnWhite{(6,5)}\TextOnBlack{(6,6)}\TextOnWhite{(6,7)}\TextOnBlack{(6,8)}\\
\TextOnBlack{(5,1)}\TextOnWhite{(5,2)}\TextOnBlack{(5,3)}\TextOnWhite{(5,4)}%
\TextOnBlack{(5,5)}\TextOnWhite{(5,6)}\TextOnBlack{(5,7)}\TextOnWhite{(5,8)}\\
\TextOnWhite{(4,1)}\TextOnBlack{(4,2)}\TextOnWhite{(4,3)}\TextOnBlack{(4,4)}%
\TextOnWhite{(4,5)}\TextOnBlack{(4,6)}\TextOnWhite{(4,7)}\TextOnBlack{(4,8)}\\
\TextOnBlack{(3,1)}\TextOnWhite{(3,2)}\TextOnBlack{(3,3)}\TextOnWhite{(3,4)}%
\TextOnBlack{(3,5)}\TextOnWhite{(3,6)}\TextOnBlack{(3,7)}\TextOnWhite{(3,8)}\\
\TextOnWhite{(2,1)}\TextOnBlack{(2,2)}\TextOnWhite{(2,3)}\TextOnBlack{(2,4)}%
\TextOnWhite{(2,5)}\TextOnBlack{(2,6)}\TextOnWhite{(2,7)}\TextOnBlack{(2,8)}\\
\TextOnBlack{(1,1)}\TextOnWhite{(1,2)}\TextOnBlack{(1,3)}\TextOnWhite{(1,4)}%
\TextOnBlack{(1,5)}\TextOnWhite{(1,6)}\TextOnBlack{(1,7)}\TextOnWhite{(1,8)}
}\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Overlaying the text on top of `\WhiteEmptySquare` is sort of wasteful but the [`chessfss`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chessfss) package sometimes uses two different colors, not just black and white.

Comment: Why didn't you use looping approach to save more keystrokes?

Comment: For a one-off, I'd rather type than debug.

Answer (score 14):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,8}
\foreach \y in {1,2,...,8}
{
\draw (\x,\y) +(-.5,-.5) rectangle ++(.5,.5);
\draw (\x,\y) node{\small (\y,\x)};
}
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,8}{
\node at (\x,0) {\x};
\node at (0,\x) {\x};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A MetaPost solution, drawing something like a real chessboard, for the fun:

```
input latexmp; setupLaTeXMP(textextlabel = enable, mode = rerun);
u := 1.5cm; 
n := 8;
picture mypoint;
beginfig(1);
  for i = 1 upto n:
    for j = 1 upto n:
      mypoint := thelabel("$(" & decimal j & "," & decimal i & ")$", u*(i-.5, j-.5));
      if (i+j) mod 2 = 0:
        fill ((i-1, j-1) -- (i, j-1) -- (i, j) -- (i-1, j) -- cycle) scaled u;
        draw mypoint withcolor white;
      else: draw mypoint;
      fi;
    endfor;
    label.bot("$" & decimal i & "$", u*(i-.5, 0));
    label.lft("$" & decimal i & "$", u*(0, i-.5));
  endfor;
  draw (origin -- (n, 0) -- (n, n) -- (0, n) -- cycle) scaled u;
  setbounds currentpicture to boundingbox currentpicture enlarged 2bp;
endfig;
end.
```

If interested, typeset it with the Metafun format. For example, to obtain a PDF version directly, you can enter this in a command line:

```
mptopdf -metafun -latex chessboard.mp
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution using the [`xfp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xfp) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{dimen = m}
\usepackage{xfp}

% Constants. 
\newcommand*\shift[1]{\fpeval{#1-0.5}}
\newcommand*\size[1]{\fpeval{\squaresize*#1}}
\newcommand*\maximum{\fpeval{\squaresize*\boardsize}}

% Parameters.
\def\squaresize{1}
\def\boardsize{8}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.3,-0.4)(\maximum,\maximum)
  \multido{\iB = 1+1}{\boardsize}{%
    \uput[180](0,\shift{\iB}){$\iB$}
    \uput[270](\shift{\iB},0){$\iB$}
    \multido{\iA = 1+1}{\boardsize}{%
      \psframe(\size{\iA-1},\size{\iB-1})(\size{\iA},\size{\iB})
      \rput(\size{\shift{\iB}},\size{\shift{\iA}}){$(\iA,\iB)$}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is choose the value of `\squaresize` and `\boardsize`.

Comment: Svend, You code does not compile. I get an error on the last line. Hakarl

Answer (score 2):

Just another much better solution with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](8,8)
    \multido{\ix=1+1,\ic=97+1}{8}
    {% <--- I really don't understand why we need to append % here right before \pstVerb.
        \pstVerb{/hx \ix\space .5 sub def}
        \uput[d](!hx 0){$\char\ic\mathstrut$}
        \uput[l](!0 hx){$\ix\mathstrut$}
        \multido{\iy=1+1,\io=\ix+1}{8}
        {       
            \psframe[origin={\ix,\iy},fillstyle=\ifodd\io solid\else vlines\fi,hatchsep=.5pt,hatchcolor=lightgray](-1,-1)
            \rput(!hx \iy\space .5 sub){$(\iy,\ix)$}
        }
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't compile it. Appears the errors: Line 15 - Missing number, treated as zero and Line 15 -Illegal unit measure (pt inserted)

Comment: @benedito: Compile it with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence or `xelatex`.

Comment: I tried - To see the message that appears : Miktex Problem Report:Windows API error 2
The system cannot find the file specified.(before I saved archive)