# Drawing checkers/draughts boards and positions in LaTeX

Tags: chessboard

Is there a good way of drawing draughts/checkers boards with LaTeX? I know that there are several excellent chess-related packages by Ulrike Fischer but I could not see a way of drawing a checkers position without resorting to using the chess pawn image (font) to represent a checkers man and, similarly, using the chess king image (font) to represent a checkers king.

Comment: I don't know any package. But if chessboard works generally, this means that you only need a suitable font. Do you have one?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168281/how-to-draw-a-chessboard-with-numbers/168304?r=SearchResults&s=1|47.5503#168304