# Irregular Chessboard and Labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, chessboard

I need to type only half triangular part of a chessboard with different coloring setting and label the rows and columns not by a,b,...;1,2,... but by other letters. More explicitly, I need to type something like the following figure but I couldn't find anyway to do this with any package. Are there any simple way to do this?

[image]

Comment: There is a package called tikz based on pgf plots. You would have to read yourself into it, but trust me it is worth it! :D
http://www.texample.net/tikz/

Comment: chessboard is for chess, not for arbitrary collections of square fields. Use tikz for this.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168281/how-to-draw-a-chessboard-with-numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start from following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,
    nodes={draw, fill, minimum size=9mm}]
    {~&~&~&~&|[fill=white]|~&|[fill=white]|~&|[fill=white]|~\\
     &~&~&~&|[fill=white]|~&|[fill=white]|~&|[fill=white]|~\\
     &&~&~&|[fill=white]|~&|[fill=white]|~&|[fill=white]|~\\
     &&&~&~&~&~\\
     &&&&~&~&~\\
     &&&&&~&~\\
     &&&&&&~\\};
    \foreach \i [count=\ni from 4, count=\nj from 2] in {1,...,7}{ 
        \node[right=1mm of A-\i-7.east]{$a_{1\nj}$};
        \node[above=1mm of A-1-\i.north]{$a_{\ni(11)}$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, an alternative that fills the entries programmatically.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,row
sep=-3*\pgflinewidth,nodes={align=center,minimum width=4em,minimum height=4em,
/utils/exec=\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<8
\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow>1 
 \ifnum\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+1\relax>\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1\relax
  \ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn>4
   \ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow<5
    \tikzset{draw,fill=white}
   \else
    \tikzset{draw,fill}
   \fi
   \else
   \tikzset{draw,fill}
  \fi 
 \else
 \fi
\fi
\fi,
execute at begin node={\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=1%
\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<8% 
$a_{\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+3\relax(11)}$%
\fi%
\else%
\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=8% 
$a_{1\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}$%
\fi%
\fi%
}}] (mat)
 {& & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & &\\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]