# A chess board according to moves

Tags: xetex, chessboard

I'm sure that this question has been answered elsewhere: I would like to know ho do I type this:
1.d4

[image]

in a `XeTeX` file.

Comment: Thank you for green check mark, but the better answer is of @UlrikeFischer. Please can you give this. I am happy thus. :-)

Comment: I draw my own chessboards, so can do pretty much anything with them.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168281/how-to-draw-a-chessboard-with-numbers/168304?r=SearchResults&s=1|50.3108#168304

Comment: @JohnKormylo I vote up your question indicated in the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using `skak` package without the option [ps] that not have the black square:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skak}
\begin{document}
\newgame
\mainline{1. d4}
\[ \showboard \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**: showing the black with the arrow (with the option ps) ....whose next move is by the black player.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ps]{skak}
\showmoverOn
\begin{document}
\newgame
\mainline{1.d4}
\storegame{game1}
\[ \showboard \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the black square is asymbol to show who's move it is, and there is a skak option for it too (and it can naturally be suppressed with xskak/chessboard).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I like the chess. But if the first move is by the white pawn, shouldn't there be a white square indicating that the first move is by the "white" player?

Comment: the board shows the position *after*  the white  move, the next move will be a black move.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah now I have understood...now I put an addendum....but I not want the green check mark ...hence I have put the community wiki  :-)))))

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1. d4}

\chessboard
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am sure totally that the answer was your :-). But skak package is it obsolete? I have used this.