# Re-creating Tikz image with other package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have an **array** in my latex template something like this:

[image]

This picture is made with `Tikz`. Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [
                        nodes in empty cells,
                        nodes={minimum size=10mm},
                        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                        column sep=-\pgflinewidth
                    ]
    border/.style={draw}
    
    \tikzstyle{bg_gray} = [fill=gray!20]
    
    \matrix(vector)[
        matrix of nodes,
        row 1/.style={nodes={draw,font=\strut}},
        row 2/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=0.4cm}},
        nodes={draw}
        ]
    {
        |[draw=none, minimum width=1.5cm]| $\textbf{a[i]}$ & $4$ & $7$ & $10$ & |[bg_gray]| $6$ & |[bg_gray]| $4$ & |[bg_gray]| $1$ & $3$ & $6$ & $11$ & |[bg_gray]| $9$ & |[bg_gray]| $5$ \\
        \textbf{\small{i}} & \small{0} & \small{1} & \small{2} & \small{3} & \small{4} & \small{5} & \small{6} & \small{7} & \small{8} & \small{9} & \small{10} \\
    };
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A random array for observation}
\label{fig:array_observation}
\end{figure}
```

But my problem is some system like ACM doesn't allow to use `Tikz` ([List of Accepted LaTeX Packages](https://www.acm.org/publications/taps/accepted-latex-packages)).  Please suggest how I can re-create a similar image using any of other packages they allowed?

Comment: Maybe you could generate the picture with tikz and then include it as a PDF graphics in the final paper?

Comment: Have a look at the standalone package.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, does 'include it as a PDF graphics' mean add like an eps picture?

Comment: Include it as any other image (png, jpg, pdf).

Comment: You could probably do it with a tabular,   Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168281/how-to-draw-a-chessboard-with-numbers

Comment: This is what the externalisation library is for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following uses only approved packages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \makebox[25pt]{$\mathbf{Arr}[\mathbf{i}]$}
  \begin{tabular}{ | *{11}{w{c}{12pt} |} }
    \hline
      \rule[-.75\normalbaselineskip]{0pt}{2\normalbaselineskip}% Strut
      16 & 5 & 11 & 
      \cellcolor{gray!20}6 & \cellcolor{gray!20}7 & \cellcolor{gray!20}3 &
      8 & 6 & 15 &
      \cellcolor{gray!20}21 & \cellcolor{gray!20}14 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  
  \medskip
  
  \footnotesize
  \makebox[25pt]{$\mathbf{i}$}
  \begin{tabular}{ *{11}{w{c}{\dimexpr12pt+\arrayrulewidth}} }
      0 &  1 & 2 &
      3 &  4 & 5 &
      6 &  7 & 8 &
      9 & 10
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{An array $\mathbf{Arr}$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```