# Writing a Chess Book in LaTeX

Tags: books, chess, chessboard

I am interested in writing a chess book in LaTeX. Are there any existing LaTeX templates for writing Chess books in overleaf? Also, is there any streamlined way to use Chessbase directly for writing a chess book, whether it is in LaTeX or not.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168281/how-to-draw-a-chessboard-with-numbers/168304?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C49.1059#168304 and http://www.elfsoft2000.com/chess/index.htm

Comment: Also related: https://ctan.org/pkg/xskak?lang=en